# sass with compass - compile error

Tags: sass, compass-sass, compass

I try to use my private sass files together with compass and I get following error:

> "sass file.scss:file.css
>   Syntax error: (“lighten-5”: #ffebee, “lighten-4”: #ffcdd2, “lighten-3”: #ef9a9a, “lighten-2”: #e57373, “lighten-1”: #ef5350, “base”: #f44336, “darken-1”: #e53935, “darken-2”: #d32f2f, “darken-3”: #c62828, “darken-4”: #b71c1c, “accent-1”: #ff8a80, “accent-2”: #ff5252, “accent-3”: #ff1744, “accent-4”: #d50000) isn’t a valid CSS value."

And here is my .scss file which seems to cause the problem.

```css
$m-red: (
  "lighten-5":  #fdeaeb,
  "lighten-4":  #f8c1c3,
  "lighten-3":  #f3989b, 
  "lighten-2":  #ee6e73,
  "lighten-1":  #ea454b,
  "base":       #e51c23,
  "darken-1":   #d0181e,
  "darken-2":   #b9151b,
  "darken-3":   #a21318,
  "darken-4":   #8b1014,
);

$red: (
  "lighten-5":  #FFEBEE,
  "lighten-4":  #FFCDD2,
  "lighten-3":  #EF9A9A,
  "lighten-2":  #E57373,
  "lighten-1":  #EF5350,
  "base":       #F44336,
  "darken-1":   #E53935,
  "darken-2":   #D32F2F,
  "darken-3":   #C62828,
  "darken-4":   #B71C1C,
  "accent-1":    #FF8A80,
  "accent-2":    #FF5252,
  "accent-3":    #FF1744,
  "accent-4":    #D50000
);

$pink: (
  "lighten-5":  #fce4ec,
  "lighten-4":  #f8bbd0,
  "lighten-3":  #f48fb1,
  "lighten-2":  #f06292,
  "lighten-1":  #ec407a,
  "base":       #e91e63,
  "darken-1":   #d81b60,
  "darken-2":   #c2185b,
  "darken-3":   #ad1457,
  "darken-4":   #880e4f,
  "accent-1":    #ff80ab,
  "accent-2":    #ff4081,
  "accent-3":    #f50057,
  "accent-4":    #c51162
);

$purple: (
  "lighten-5":  #f3e5f5,
  "lighten-4":  #e1bee7,
  "lighten-3":  #ce93d8,
  "lighten-2":  #ba68c8,
  "lighten-1":  #ab47bc,
  "base":       #9c27b0,
  "darken-1":   #8e24aa,
  "darken-2":   #7b1fa2,
  "darken-3":   #6a1b9a,
  "darken-4":   #4a148c,
  "accent-1":    #ea80fc,
  "accent-2":    #e040fb,
  "accent-3":    #d500f9,
  "accent-4":    #aa00ff
);

$deep-purple: (
  "lighten-5":  #ede7f6,
  "lighten-4":  #d1c4e9,
  "lighten-3":  #b39ddb,
  "lighten-2":  #9575cd,
  "lighten-1":  #7e57c2,
  "base":       #673ab7,
  "darken-1":   #5e35b1,
  "darken-2":   #512da8,
  "darken-3":   #4527a0,
  "darken-4":   #311b92,
  "accent-1":    #b388ff,
  "accent-2":    #7c4dff,
  "accent-3":    #651fff,
  "accent-4":    #6200ea
);

$indigo: (
  "lighten-5":  #e8eaf6,
  "lighten-4":  #c5cae9,
  "lighten-3":  #9fa8da,
  "lighten-2":  #7986cb,
  "lighten-1":  #5c6bc0,
  "base":       #3f51b5,
  "darken-1":   #3949ab,
  "darken-2":   #303f9f,
  "darken-3":   #283593,
  "darken-4":   #1a237e,
  "accent-1":    #8c9eff,
  "accent-2":    #536dfe,
  "accent-3":    #3d5afe,
  "accent-4":    #304ffe
);

$blue: (
  "lighten-5":  #E3F2FD,
  "lighten-4":  #BBDEFB,
  "lighten-3":  #90CAF9,
  "lighten-2":  #64B5F6,
  "lighten-1":  #42A5F5,
  "base":       #2196F3,
  "darken-1":   #1E88E5,
  "darken-2":   #1976D2,
  "darken-3":   #1565C0,
  "darken-4":   #0D47A1,
  "accent-1":    #82B1FF,
  "accent-2":    #448AFF,
  "accent-3":    #2979FF,
  "accent-4":    #2962FF
);

$light-blue: (
  "lighten-5":  #e1f5fe,
  "lighten-4":  #b3e5fc,
  "lighten-3":  #81d4fa,
  "lighten-2":  #4fc3f7,
  "lighten-1":  #29b6f6,
  "base":       #03a9f4,
  "darken-1":   #039be5,
  "darken-2":   #0288d1,
  "darken-3":   #0277bd,
  "darken-4":   #01579b,
  "accent-1":    #80d8ff,
  "accent-2":    #40c4ff,
  "accent-3":    #00b0ff,
  "accent-4":    #0091ea
);

$cyan: (
  "lighten-5":  #e0f7fa,
  "lighten-4":  #b2ebf2,
  "lighten-3":  #80deea,
  "lighten-2":  #4dd0e1,
  "lighten-1":  #26c6da,
  "base":       #00bcd4,
  "darken-1":   #00acc1,
  "darken-2":   #0097a7,
  "darken-3":   #00838f,
  "darken-4":   #006064,
  "accent-1":    #84ffff,
  "accent-2":    #18ffff,
  "accent-3":    #00e5ff,
  "accent-4":    #00b8d4
);

$teal: (
  "lighten-5":  #e0f2f1,
  "lighten-4":  #b2dfdb,
  "lighten-3":  #80cbc4,
  "lighten-2":  #4db6ac,
  "lighten-1":  #26a69a,
  "base":       #009688,
  "darken-1":   #00897b,
  "darken-2":   #00796b,
  "darken-3":   #00695c,
  "darken-4":   #004d40,
  "accent-1":    #a7ffeb,
  "accent-2":    #64ffda,
  "accent-3":    #1de9b6,
  "accent-4":    #00bfa5
);

$green: (
  "lighten-5":  #E8F5E9,
  "lighten-4":  #C8E6C9,
  "lighten-3":  #A5D6A7,
  "lighten-2":  #81C784,
  "lighten-1":  #66BB6A,
  "base":       #4CAF50,
  "darken-1":   #43A047,
  "darken-2":   #388E3C,
  "darken-3":   #2E7D32,
  "darken-4":   #1B5E20,
  "accent-1":    #B9F6CA,
  "accent-2":    #69F0AE,
  "accent-3":    #00E676,
  "accent-4":    #00C853
);

$light-green: (
  "lighten-5":  #f1f8e9,
  "lighten-4":  #dcedc8,
  "lighten-3":  #c5e1a5,
  "lighten-2":  #aed581,
  "lighten-1":  #9ccc65,
  "base":       #8bc34a,
  "darken-1":   #7cb342,
  "darken-2":   #689f38,
  "darken-3":   #558b2f,
  "darken-4":   #33691e,
  "accent-1":    #ccff90,
  "accent-2":    #b2ff59,
  "accent-3":    #76ff03,
  "accent-4":    #64dd17
);

$lime: (
  "lighten-5":  #f9fbe7,
  "lighten-4":  #f0f4c3,
  "lighten-3":  #e6ee9c,
  "lighten-2":  #dce775,
  "lighten-1":  #d4e157,
  "base":       #cddc39,
  "darken-1":   #c0ca33,
  "darken-2":   #afb42b,
  "darken-3":   #9e9d24,
  "darken-4":   #827717, 
  "accent-1":    #f4ff81,
  "accent-2":    #eeff41,
  "accent-3":    #c6ff00,
  "accent-4":    #aeea00
);

$yellow: (
  "lighten-5":  #fffde7,
  "lighten-4":  #fff9c4,
  "lighten-3":  #fff59d,
  "lighten-2":  #fff176,
  "lighten-1":  #ffee58,
  "base":       #ffeb3b,
  "darken-1":   #fdd835,
  "darken-2":   #fbc02d,
  "darken-3":   #f9a825,
  "darken-4":   #f57f17,
  "accent-1":    #ffff8d,
  "accent-2":    #ffff00,
  "accent-3":    #ffea00,
  "accent-4":    #ffd600
);

$amber: (
  "lighten-5":  #fff8e1,
  "lighten-4":  #ffecb3,
  "lighten-3":  #ffe082,
  "lighten-2":  #ffd54f,
  "lighten-1":  #ffca28,
  "base":       #ffc107,
  "darken-1":   #ffb300,
  "darken-2":   #ffa000,
  "darken-3":   #ff8f00,
  "darken-4":   #ff6f00,
  "accent-1":    #ffe57f,
  "accent-2":    #ffd740,
  "accent-3":    #ffc400,
  "accent-4":    #ffab00
);

$orange: (
  "lighten-5":  #fff3e0,
  "lighten-4":  #ffe0b2,
  "lighten-3":  #ffcc80,
  "lighten-2":  #ffb74d,
  "lighten-1":  #ffa726,
  "base":       #ff9800,
  "darken-1":   #fb8c00,
  "darken-2":   #f57c00,
  "darken-3":   #ef6c00,
  "darken-4":   #e65100,
  "accent-1":    #ffd180,
  "accent-2":    #ffab40,
  "accent-3":    #ff9100,
  "accent-4":    #ff6d00
);

$deep-orange: (
  "lighten-5":  #fbe9e7,
  "lighten-4":  #ffccbc,
  "lighten-3":  #ffab91,
  "lighten-2":  #ff8a65,
  "lighten-1":  #ff7043,
  "base":       #ff5722,
  "darken-1":   #f4511e,
  "darken-2":   #e64a19,
  "darken-3":   #d84315,
  "darken-4":   #bf360c,
  "accent-1":    #ff9e80,
  "accent-2":    #ff6e40,
  "accent-3":    #ff3d00,
  "accent-4":    #dd2c00
);

$brown: (
  "lighten-5":  #efebe9,
  "lighten-4":  #d7ccc8,
  "lighten-3":  #bcaaa4,
  "lighten-2":  #a1887f,
  "lighten-1":  #8d6e63,
  "base":       #795548,
  "darken-1":   #6d4c41,
  "darken-2":   #5d4037,
  "darken-3":   #4e342e,
  "darken-4":   #3e2723
);

$blue-grey: (
  "lighten-5":  #eceff1,
  "lighten-4":  #cfd8dc,
  "lighten-3":  #b0bec5,
  "lighten-2":  #90a4ae,
  "lighten-1":  #78909c,
  "base":       #607d8b,
  "darken-1":   #546e7a,
  "darken-2":   #455a64,
  "darken-3":   #37474f,
  "darken-4":   #263238
);

$grey: (
  "lighten-5":  #fafafa,
  "lighten-4":  #f5f5f5,
  "lighten-3":  #eeeeee,
  "lighten-2":  #e0e0e0,
  "lighten-1":  #bdbdbd,
  "base":       #9e9e9e,
  "darken-1":   #757575,
  "darken-2":   #616161,
  "darken-3":   #424242,
  "darken-4":   #212121
);

$shades: (
  "black":        #000000,
  "white":        #FFFFFF,
  "transparent":  transparent
);

$colors: (
  "m-red": $m-red,
  "red": $red,
  "pink": $pink,
  "purple": $purple,
  "deep-purple": $deep-purple,
  "indigo": $indigo,
  "blue": $blue,
  "light-blue": $light-blue,
  "cyan": $cyan,
  "teal": $teal,
  "green": $green,
  "light-green": $light-green,
  "lime": $lime,
  "yellow": $yellow,
  "amber": $amber,
  "orange": $orange,
  "deep-orange": $deep-orange,
  "brown": $brown,
  "blue-grey": $blue-grey,
  "grey": $grey,
  "shades": $shades
);
```

Without compass everything compiles perfect. What's wrong with the file above?

Edit:

Isolated code:

```
$new_m-red: ( lighten-5: #fdeaeb); 

$new_colors: ( "m-red": $m-red);
// Color Classes
@each $color_name,
$color in $new_colors {
    @each $color_type,
    $color_value in $color{
        @if $color_type=="base" {
            .#{$color_name} {
                background-color: $color_value !important;
            }
            .#{$color_name}-text {
                color: $color_value !important;
            }
        }
        @else {
            .#{$color_name}.#{$color_type} {
                background-color: $color_value !important;
            }
            .#{$color_name}-text.text-#{$color_type} {
                color: $color_value !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compass version: 
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)

SASS Sass 3.4.19 (Selective Steve)

> error: 
>    modified /sass/file/_color.scss
>       error /sass/file.scss (Line 49 of /sass/file/_color.scss: ("lighten-5": #fdeaeb) isn't a valid CSS value.)

I tried without quotes:

> modified /sass/file/_color.scss
>       error /sass/file.scss (Line 49 of /sass/file/free/_color.scss: (lighten-5: #fdeaeb) isn't a valid CSS value.)

Comment: I am voting to close this as a typographical error:  you're looping over the same variable ($new_colors) on both the inner and outer loop, rather than using $color on the inner loop.

Comment: Your right, that is my fault however even after fixing that (using $color inside internal loop) the error is exactly the same...

Comment: Then you've failed to provide enough code to reproduce the error: http://sassmeister.com/gist/4b06a1b8dbe7851903ef

Comment: remove comma in ..."darken-4":   #8b1014,..